# Why don't Apple want a download all music in their Apple Music App?

Tags: apple-music

I'm very curious as to why Apple doesn't want to implement a download all music feature like Spotify. It's very inconvenient and I hate having to download each music respectively.

Answer (score 1):

There is option in iTunes -> Preferences ->  Downloads -> Automatic Downloads but it's for purchased music or Apple Music. In iTunes Tab you can download each Playlist with the ... Tab Download all. Till yet Apple don't allow it because of iTunes Match and Apple Music. Where with a simple MacBook with 250GB SSD it's not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. What about Apple Music on Android phones?